# structure Look forward to hearing

Tags: grammaticality

I have an idea with this structure and I am not sure it is correct or not. Please help me

1. I look forward to hearing from you.
2. I look forward to your hearing.
3. I look forward to a hearing of yours.

In my opinion I think 3 sentences is correct. Could you guys help me check this ?

Comment: Nope, it's number 1). You should be aware that "hearing" has another use which makes 2) and 3)  sound like a court appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is the most natural to me
2. A "hearing" is an aspect of a criminal trial, so this makes it sound like you are looking forward to your friend being punished.
3. Same as 2 but "a hearing of yours" instead of "your hearing" makes it sound like this friend has multiple hearings, and you are looking forward to one of them.

If you wanted to use a similar structure as 2 you could replace "hearing" with "message" in #2. #3 Doesn't really work unless you change it to "this message" but the tone makes it sound like you don't think the message exists.

Comment: Thank you. I definetely follow your advice. (Y)